# How to quickly navigate to Redux reducer from an Action in WebStorm?

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, redux, react-redux, webstorm

I have to write a Redux application using @reduxjs/toolkit

Here are the Redux actions in `todoActions.js`

```js
// todoActions.js

import {createAction} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const TodoActions = {

  /**
   * @function
   * @param {String} todo
   */
    addTodo: createAction("addTodo"),
  
  /**
   * @function
   * @param {String} todoId
   */
  removeTodo: createAction("removeTodo"),
    
};

export default TodoActions;
```

and the reducer stays in `todoReducer.js`

```js
import {createReducer} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import TodoActions from "../todoActions";

const initState = {
  todos: [],
};

const reducer = createReducer(initState, {
  [TodoActions.addTodo]: (state, action) => {
    state.todos = [state.todos, ...action.payload];
  },

  [TodoActions.removeTodo]: (state, action) => {
    state.todos = state.todos.filter(x=>x.id!==action.payload);
  },
  
});

export default reducer;
```

And here is how I use actions in a React Component

```js
import React from 'react'
import {useDispatch} from 'redux-react-hook'
import TodoActions from './todoActions'

const AddRandomButton () {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  
  const clickHandler = event => {
    dispatch(TodoActions.addTodo("some random todos"))
  }
  
  return (
     <button onclick={clickHandler}>
       Add
     </button>
  )
  
}
```

The problem is that: it is not easy to navigate from an action to its appropriate logic.
When I <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+CLICK on the `addTodo()` inside `AddButton` component, the IDE will jump to the definition of the `addTodo()`, which shows nothing about the logic of this function, because the logic is in the reducer.

Question: Is there any plugin or tips how to quickly go to the reducer instead of the action definition in IntelliJ/WebStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a Redux maintainer and creator of Redux Toolkit.

I would **strongly recommend that you use `createSlice` instead of `createAction/createReducer`  directly**.

There's no reason to define the action creators separately here, and the fact that you're doing them separately is what's causing the problem you're describing.

In addition, the object wrapping the todos array is unnecessary in this case.

I would write this as:

```js
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = [];

const todosSlice = createSlice({
    name: "todos",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addTodo(state, action) {
            state.push(action.payload);
        },
        removeTodo(state, action) {
            return state.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload);
        }
    }
});

export const {addTodo, removeTodo} = todosSlice.actions;
export default todosSlice.reducer;
```

and then pull it together at the app level like:

```js
import {combineReducers} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import todosReducer from "features/todosSlice";

export default combineReducers({
    todos: todosReducer,
});
```

This way, when you right-click and "Go to Definition" on `addTodo`, it'll jump straight to the file that has the reducer logic as well.  (And, you'll have fewer files to deal with.)

Comment: thanks @markerikson, your solution is exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: Hi @markerikson, is there any way to describe the parameters of the actions. So that WebStorm can understand and make code suggestion.

Comment: Sure, use JSDoc or TypeScript.